# Credit memo gives: Total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract

Tags: creditmemo, exception

Credit memos always worked fine on my friends store, he tried a few plugins, which he cannot recall also in specfic order/detail. They all got deleted off the server and yes, he did this in the live environment.

Problem is: Now all goes well until a credit memo is needed, We then get: There has been an error processing your request ... Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

With a log ID number. Here is the full log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract.";i:1;s:1885:"#0 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Total/Config/Base.php(70): Mage::throwException('Total model sho...')
#1 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Config/Ordered.php(83): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Config_Base->_initModelInstance('Mage_Fee_Model_...', 'fee', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Total/Config/Base.php(88): Mage_Sales_Model_Config_Ordered->_initModels()
#3 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php(329): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Config_Base->getTotalModels()
#4 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Order.php(208): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo->collectTotals()
#5 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreditmemoController.php(138): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order->prepareCreditmemo(Array)
#6 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreditmemoController.php(222): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreditmemoController->_initCreditmemo()
#7 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreditmemoController->newAction()
#8 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#9 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/robbshop/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/robbshop/public_html/index.php(84): Mage::run('nl')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:96:"/index.php/beheer/sales_order_creditmemo/new/order_id/1465/key/b33de54d5125a4cfa9a7302dea027a0b/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Anybody else seen this before ? We cannot find the answer here and we'd like to use credit memo's still.

What I have tried: clearing all cache files in the backend and on the ftp server, but it is starting to feel like sql corruption :S And I looked at folder/file rights, all is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is there:

> Total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract.

You or one of your installed modules adds a total model which is not extended from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract`.

Use xdebug, hook into the `Mage::throwException()` line in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Total/Config/Base.php (Line 70)
```

and check which model produces the error. Then you can either disable it or fix the bug.

What you can else do:

When you know the name of the total model, check the table `config_core_data` for an entry, maybe the config is read from there. A plugin might have added the config and just uninstalling doesn't reset the database.

And for the next time: first try new plugins at home, before throwing them on your end customers.

Comment: Giftcard extension seemed to ruin this indeed, thnx !

Comment: You could also echo the class before Mage::throwException and search for it in your app folder. Like #69: echo $class; exit; The class name shows up if you hit the "Credit Memo" button and you can grep for it.